# How do we get back that few seconds preview of death in Call of Duty 4 multiplayer?

Tags: call-of-duty-4-modern-warfare

Normally whenever we die in Call of Duty 4 Modern Warfare multi-player we get a few seconds preview from the enemy's perspective. It shows how he killed us. I think it lasts about 6-8 seconds. For some reason it has stopped showing up when I die. How do I get it to start showing up again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are playing any hardcore style game type it doesn't show your opponent on the kill cam.  This is intentional and adds to the feeling of vulnerability that hardcore mode is designed to instill.  In addition it prevents 'run backers' who immediately spawn and try and invoke vengeance on who ever killed them.

To regain that kill cam, simply change to non-hardcore game types or (if on pc: find a lobby that has kill cams enabled)

Comment: If hosting your own server, enable kill cams.

Comment: oh so its a server configuration is it? In other words it depends on the server I connect to?

Comment: @Mugen you got it, the server can disable or enable kill cam depending on their personal preferences.